# Prediction region for multiple multivariate Gaussian observations

Tags: prediction, multivariate-normal-distribution

Consider a sample of *iid* observations from a multivariate normal distribution, how to get a prediction region for multiple new observations ?

### The approach in the univariate case

Let the statistical model given by observations $y_1, \ldots, y_n \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$.
Consider two new observations $y^\ast_1$, $y^\ast_2$.

It is easy to check that the pair $x:=\left(\frac{y^\ast_1-\bar y}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}\hat\sigma}, \frac{y^\ast_2-\bar y}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}\hat\sigma}\right)$ follows a centered multivariate Student distribution with scale matrix $S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{n+1} \\ \frac{1}{n+1} & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and number of degrees of freedom $n-1$.

By a known result on the multivariate Student distribution,  $\frac{1}{2}x'S^{-1}x$ follows the Fisher distribution $F(2, n-1)$.

From this, one can derive a prediction ellipsoid for $(y^\ast_1, y^\ast_2)$.

### Multivariate case

Now, let the statistical model given by multivariate observations $y_1, \ldots, y_n \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}(\mu, \Sigma)$.
Consider two new observations $y^\ast_1$, $y^\ast_2$.

How to derive a prediction region for $(y^\ast_1, y^\ast_2)$ ?

It is known how to derive a prediction ellipsoid for a single observation, with the help of an Hotelling statistic. 
Namely, denoting by $\hat\Sigma$ the unbiased estimate of $\Sigma$, it is known that, denoting by $d=2$ the dimension, 
$$
\frac{n}{n+1} \times \frac{n-d}{d(n-1)} \times {(y^\ast_1 - \bar y)}' \hat\Sigma^{-1} {(y^\ast_1 - \bar y)} \sim F(d, n-d).
$$
From this result one can get a prediction ellispoid for the single new observation $y^\ast_1$.

But how to get a prediction region for the pair $(y^\ast_1, y^\ast_2)$ ? 
I have heard about matrix-valued Student and Fisher distributions, I don't know whether these distributions could occur here and help to solve the problem.